# Operations between rotating elements

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mathematics, machine-design, machine-elements

Given two (or more) rotating elements, which mathematical operations can be done between them?

For example:

- Different gear ratios can be used to multiply a rotating element's angular velocity by a fixed scalar.
- A differential gear can be used to average the angular velocity of two axles. If we then multiply the result by two (see point above), we have a way to add angular velocities.
- I'm fairly sure a clever arrangement with a CVT gear system can be used to "multiply" the angular velocity of two rotating elements.

Is there a systematic approach to this? Can someone point me to some reference material?

Comment: Many textbooks exist, one is Mechanics of Machines by Ryder & Bennet.

Comment: I've had a look at the index, and it seems to be a regular textbook on the principle of mechanics. What I'm looking for is a more systematic analysis (from an abstract standpoint, mostly) of the possible mathematical operations between rotating parts.

Comment: So, only several hundred other books to check.

Comment: Lovely, can you point me to one?

Comment: I did, but not doing your research for you. Can't even be bothered to check in my own library.